# How to draw a balanced random sample given prediction confidence and model performance?

Tags: sampling, svm

**INTRO**

I have trained a SVM model based on 300 training cases in order to build a filter that should help me extract a bigger and evenly balanced training set, that is to be validated by human judges.

**DATA**

My training set is:

```
288 negative cases
12 positive cases
```

My model performance is:

```
True positives = 6
False positives = 0
True negatives = 288
False negative = 6
```

I have used this model on a 440000 cases data set and I am given confidence values for zeroes and ones (confidence.1. = 95% -> confidence.0. = 5% and confidence.1. = 50% -> confidence.0. = 50%)

When the model is applied to the 440000 cased it predicts 1499 of the cases to be positive.

**PROBLEM**

As explained I am about to take a random sample of 3000 cases that will hopefully be balanced in order to train a better model. Thus my formal problem becomes:

*"How can one extract a random sample of 3000 and approximate the balance of the dataset given the information I have stated?"*

**OWN THOUGHTS**

I am fairly good with R but I simply do not have the knowledge or the skills to figure this out. I dont even know if it is possible. The only thing I do know is that it seems a bit doll to just put a finger in the air and guess on which cases to extract. The easy way would be to take the top 3000 sorted on confidence.1. which is nothing more that a qualified guess.
Happy new year
Kasper